# How can view controller present it's self?

Tags: ios, swift, class, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I have the following class below.  The idea is it will use a custom Progress Window View Controller to handle progress of various different events.  The problem is since this is in a class and not a view controller it's self, I'm not sure how to make the progressWindow actually show up after I instantiate it from the storyboard?

How do I do this? Currently I get an error that the application tried to present model view controller on itself.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class StatusProgress{
    static var cancelCode = {}
    static var runCode = {}
    static var theProgressWindowController = ProgressWindowViewController()
    static var returningViewControllerIdentifier = ""
    static let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    static func run(){
        // This will run in parralel but on main queue.  Has to be on this Queue because it might involve UI
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            // Update the UI on the main thread.
            StatusProgress.runCode()
        });

    }

    static func cancel(){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            StatusProgress.cancelCode()
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(returningViewControllerIdentifier)
                vc.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        });
    }

    static func show(){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            theProgressWindowController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("progressWindow") as! ProgressWindowViewController
            theProgressWindowController.presentViewController(theProgressWindowController, animated: true, completion: nil) //use own instance to show it's self? (throws error! application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is <Inventory_Counter.ProgressWindowViewController: 0x1466ea390>.')
        })
    }
}
```

My **problem** is essentially I need a **replacement for this line of code.**

```
theProgressWindowController.presentViewController(theProgressWindowController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I forgot to mention here is the code that runs it inside another view controller.

**SyncViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class SyncViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func yesSyncButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        StatusProgress.returningViewControllerIdentifier = "syncWindow"
        StatusProgress.runCode = {
            print("run code test")
        }
        StatusProgress.cancelCode = {
            print("cancel code test")
        }
        StatusProgress.show()
    }

    @IBAction func noSyncActionButton(sender: UIButton) {
        tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1 //assume back to inventory section
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest problem is that your `StatusProgress` class is instantiating and showing a view controller. View controllers should instantiate and show other view controllers, model objects should not. So you need to move the logic for presenting the new view controller into you `SyncViewController`. Then use delegation to communicate to the `SyncViewController` that the syncing is done.

```
protocol StatusProgressDelegate {
  func statusProgress(status: StatusProgress, shouldShow: Bool)
  func statusProgress(status: StatusProgress, shouldCancel: Bool)
}
```

Your `StatusProgress` object would have a delegate that conforms to that protocol and call that delegate inside of its show and cancel methods. This means that you need to make the static functions instance methods, and write an initializer for the class so you can instantiate it.

Comment: How would I send the delegate messages? This is interesting idea and I like it.  Can you update with example if possible?

Comment: This is a super basic iOS design pattern. If you've ever used table views or collection views, you've already used this pattern. You send the delegate messages by calling the functions listed in the protocol on the delegate object. You can find more information here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Comment: I'm not sure why this is so hard for me to figure out.  I get delegates but not sure how to use it in this situation.  I'll keep trying been at it for 8 hours :).  I'll post up my answer if it works and accept this soon.

Comment: Okay almost done with delegation method, this is what I came up with (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495208/how-can-swift-closure-reference-properties-of-class-its-running-from), but stuck on another problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the view life cycle events are not much important for you, you may just add the view of your progress controller to view of your current controller. or it's even better if you supply the UIView parameter in your `show()` function.

```
static func show(attachToView: UIView ){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            theProgressWindowController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("progressWindow") as! ProgressWindowViewController
             attachToView.addSubview(theProgressWindowController.view)
        })
    }
```

After all you'd better to remove your progress view from superview

```
   static func cancel(){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                theProgressWindowController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("progressWindow") as! ProgressWindowViewController
                 theProgressWindowController.view.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        }
```

Comment: This is interesting tactic as well.  Do you think the answer above by Chandler is better way to go heximal, or is the way you described still good?

Comment: as you mentioned, your progress control is not quite a controller, so yes, I think my approach is usable. I even can point at similar control using the same tactic. Here it is [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)